# From numpy array a remove all items present in array b -- Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a better way to do this? I used np.setdiff1D and the output I was expecting was 5. if [1, 2, 3, 4] is the correct answer. could someone explain in detail why? Thanks!**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

result = np.setdiff1d(a, b)
print(result)

# Output
[1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect 5.

Comment: Or... you could take my feedback and explain why you expect 5, so that we can understand you and help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, `setdiff1d(ar1, ar2)` returns the unique values in `ar1` that are not in `ar2`.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html

`[1, 2, 3, 4]` are the unique values in `a` that are not in `b`. And that accomplishes what the title of your posts asks for: `5` is the only unique value in `a` that is also in `b`, so that's the only value not present after the operation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation Michael, appreciated. I think i read the question wrongly!